# Modify the max value of loop in java (for and while, ..)

Tags: java

I try to change the maximum value of my loop to extend treatment;
when I change the maximum value as follows, everything works as I want:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer n=10;
        int i=0;
        List<String> lis = new ArrayList<>();
        while (i<n) {
            i++;
            //System.err.println(n);
            lis.add("1");
            //chengeMaxvalue(n, lis);
            System.out.println(n);
            n=20;// this line modify the limit value in loop
        }
        lis.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static void chengeMaxvalue(int n, List<String> lis) {
        lis.add("2");
        n=20; // this line don't modify the limit value in loop
    }
}
```

but when I try to modify it inside a nested function (// comment code), it doesn't work. But for the list, I can add element inside the nested function.

Are the scopes of `int` and `List` different?

Comment: Java pass parameters by value (so a copy of the value is made and used locally in the method i.e. value you change is local to the method).Thus, the value is not reflected back

Comment: To add to what @Shubham said too, you also do not need to name your parameters the same as the variables passed.  You are confusing yourself by using `chengeMaxvalue(int n, List<String> list)` when you can name them literally anything, it does not need to match the name inside of `main`.

Comment: thank you for yours answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the `chengeMaxvalue` method is that the arguments to the method are passed by value for `int` values (rather than by reference). Therefore, the value of `n` passed into the method is a copy of the `n` variable in the `main` method, not the same value in memory.

To solve this, you can have a `static` variable outside of both `main` and `changeMaxvalue` and alter its value in the `changeMaxvalue` method:

```
public class Test {

    private static int n = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i=0;
        List<String> lis = new ArrayList<>();
        while (i<n) {
            i++;
            lis.add("1");
            System.out.println(n);
            changeMaxvalue(lis);
        }
        lis.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    private static void chengeMaxvalue(List<String> lis) {
        lis.add("2");
        n=20;
    }

}
```

You can also encapsulate the upper bound in a class so that the method argument is passed by reference, rather than passed by value:

```
public class UpperBound {

    private int n;

    public UpperBound(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UpperBound upperBound = new UpperBound(10);
        int i=0;
        List<String> lis = new ArrayList<>();
        while (i < upperBound.getN()) {
            i++;
            lis.add("1");
            System.out.println(n);
            changeMaxvalue(upperBound, lis);
        }
        lis.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    private static void chengeMaxvalue(UpperBound upperBound, List<String> lis) {
        lis.add("2");
        upperBound.setN(20);
    }

}
```

For more information on passing by value vs. passing by reference, see [Passing by Value vs. Passing by Reference in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/pass-by-value-vs-reference-in-java).

Comment: So the list are passed as reference ?

Comment: Technically, everything is passed by value in Java. For primitives, the value is copied. For objects, the reference is copied. So, for objects, the object passed into the method and the object inside the method point to the same object. This means doing `lis = new ArrayList<>()` inside `changeMaxvalue` *wouldn't* reassign the `lis` value passed inside `main` (since the `lis` passed to `changeMaxvalue` is a *copy* of the reference, not the original reference). The article above goes into detail about the differences between passing primitives and objects.